# Как создать URL наугад

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

Вот например есть сайт `site.ru/p(.php)`.И на этой странице есть например фотка с чем, что я хочу, чтобы кто-то нажал. Например на кнопку и чтобы там отображался `site.ru/p/#FYUOPLB`(наугад) и там что-то. Главный вопрос как создать такие "Наугадные" `URL` и использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы реализовал это так:

```
<?php
$token = md5(rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX));
echo '<a href="site.ru/p/img.php?token='.$token.'">New Tag</a>';
?>
```

А на странице где есть проверка:

```
<?php

$token_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//и уже тут анализируй url

?>
```

И файл .htaccess нужно настроить так:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)?$ img.php?token=$1 [L,QSA] #тут нужно указать физический адрес страницы обработчика, например img.php
```

Comment: Я вам блогадарен это лучше! Спасибо за труд

Comment: А можно кое что спросить например нажал на ссылку а new tag там открылось site.ru/#cbsj1q3190.... и там пишет404-такой страницы нет  использовать все такие наугадные страницы?

Comment: В этом случае, вам нужно использовать .htaccess

Comment: Немного переделал код, чтобы все работало, обратите внимание

Comment: Так сейчас попробую! Спасибо

Comment: Все сработало блогадарю вас!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так.
Все ссылки сохраняй в зашифрованном виде на сервере. Когда ты переходишь по этой ссылке - браузер запрашивает данные по данному url. На сервере (в запросе) ты смотришь что зашифровано - отправляешь результат.

Comment: А отличная идея попробую щас